# firefox not display resized thumb images

Tags: image, firefox, header, http-headers, nginx

I created one function running  at Nginx server that provide resize some images and display website.Normally this function works like a charm at google chrome and display all images correctly but not firefox,ie browsers. Firefox version is 8.0

My function' some codes at below:

```
function cache_oku($fullpath){
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo file_get_contents($fullpath);

}
Calling funciton type is so ;
<img src="<?php echo 'http://mydomain.com/thumb.phpimage=http://xxxx.net/01.jpg&width=640';?>">
```

1-When I realize that, I think this issue becoz of insufficient header infos.Then I tried to add more headers with function but nothing changed.

2-Then I create new project and move this function under other my website that running server Apache, and when I build it, the images display all browsers.

Same method works website that running apache,not nginx.

Why its so ? and how I can fix that problem ?